# jQuery validation plugin: DO NOT validate form if all fields are empty

Tags: jquery, validation

I have searched through out the topics that related to my problem and found no useful answer.

This is my scenario. I have a form that have 30-40 input fields including text, radio, dropdown, file input and etc...

I have set many input fields as required on the rules section of jQuery validation plugin and these are working fine. Now, my customer says it should only validate all fields if the user filled out any. If the user filled out nothing and clicks the submit button the form should not be validated and sends empty values to the server for further process.

Can you please give me the solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this perticular case we can take a boolean variable like anyOneTextfilled=false and can check its value if anyone of the field would be filled by the user we can set its value to true if not let it be false.
Now we will check if it false only then we will show the message else it don not validate the form and save that empty values.